# User Permission changes for BigTable

Tags: permissions, gcloud, google-cloud-bigtable

For the past 2 months our IAM user / roles setup had succeeded in allowing BigTable access.

For the past two days; we are hitting permission errors for user accounts (service accounts are still able to access BigTable)

We are hitting the the user permission errors in the web UI:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

[image]

And when using a user account credentials from

```
"com.google.cloud.bigtable" % "bigtable-hbase-1.x"
```

Stack-trace:

```
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:517)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.async.AbstractRetryingOperation.onError(AbstractRetryingOperation.java:165)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.async.AbstractRetryingOperation.onClose(AbstractRetryingOperation.java:143)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.RetryingReadRowsOperation.onClose(RetryingReadRowsOperation.java:203)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.ChannelPool$InstrumentedChannel$2.onClose(ChannelPool.java:210)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:41)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor$UnAuthResponseListener.onClose(RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.java:416)
```

Are there recent changes to more strictly enforce `permissions` listed in `https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/access-control` - so should we update IAM roles?

Edit 1:
Tried updating role to include the below; but same errors still occurring:

[image]

Edit 2:
Three days later; the issue resolved and Google reverted access rights back to how they had worked (Users accounts could again see data.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting the issue. Would you mind submitting a support ticket to help us investigate?

Here is a link:
https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Thanks!

Comment: Hi; could you share a link to report the issue at? I checked https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/support - but didn't spot another channel to use to raise a ticket
Thanks